# Summation Of Primes Below a Given Number in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

I have written the following block of code to calculate the sum of all the primes below a certain number-2 000 000 in this case to be precise, however it takes quite some time to execute; 20 second:

```
def summation_of_primes_below_n(n):
list = []
sum = 0
for i in range(2, n):
    if checks_if_prime(i) == True:
        list.append(i)
return list
for j in list:
    sum = sum + j
return sum

def checks_if_prime(n):
    if n == 2:
        return True
    import math
    for i in range(2, math.ceil(math.sqrt(n))+1):
        if n%i == 0:
            return False
        elif i == math.ceil(math.sqrt(n)):
            return True

print(summation_of_primes_below_n(2000000))
```

So I was wondering if there was a way to make my code more efficient. I would greatly appreciate suitable advice on the same. Also, I would prefer that you give more basic solutions since I am a beginner and provide the logic for the same. Thanks a lot!

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2068372/3651800

Comment: Mind fixing the indentation in your code? It can't be reproduced as-is.

Answer (score 2):

You can start off by implementing some better algorithm. For eg: [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Python)

Or if you are happy with your current logic, then few optimizations that can help:

- Check only for odd numbers:

  `for i in range(3, n, 2):`
- Check only for numbers of form [6n+1, 6n+5](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/six.html)
- You don't need to do this check :  `elif i == math.ceil(math.sqrt(n)):` for each iteration. If the control reached beyond the loop then the number is prime
- You can convert your `check_prime` to  `generator pattern`. Could save some redundancy and possibly improve locality of reference.

Comment: The sieve of Eratosthenes is the best thing here since we know how far we want to go.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Ah yes. Missed it somehow.